# Why can't I convert [](auto&&...){} into a std::function<void()>?

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda

When I try to compile this:

```
#include <functional>

void f(std::function<void()> f)
{
}

void g()
{
  f([](auto&&...){});
}
```

on gcc 7.3, I get the following error:

> [x86-64 gcc 7.3 #1] error: could not convert '`<lambda closure object>g()::<lambda(auto:1&&, ...)>{}`' from '`g()::<lambda(auto:1&&, ...)>`' to '`std::function<void()>`'

Can someone explain why this is invalid c++?  Or should I submit a bug report?  (MSVC 14 accepts and compiles it to what I expect.)

Comment: As a workaround you can wrap the variadic lambda into another lambda taking no arguments.

Comment: [It compiles fine with Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78c3941e4f41635c), and I don't see why it wouldn't. Four leek slices on a compiler bug.

Comment: I bet for the compiler bug too (clang is ok)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64095). It interprets your lambda as follow:

```
[](auto&&, ...){}
```

So there's one argument, followed by C variadic.

If you add a name to your parameter pack, then it works as intended:

```
[](auto&&... pack){}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I couldn't figure out how to search for it.